# How to Access log in credentials in another activity

Tags: android, service

Here iam working with web services i need to access username and password variabes from my MainActivity to MainActivity2 below is the code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String username ;
    String password;

    public void doLgin(View view) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.LAX;
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        username = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername)).getText().toString();
        password = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword)).getText().toString();

        try {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://182.18.163.39/train/m/login.php?username=" + username + "&key=" + password);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(responseString);
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
            jsonObj.put("Result", jsonarray);
            String error = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Result").getJSONObject(0).toString();
            String errormsg = "{\"Error\":\"Problem with authentication,Please login.\"}";

            if (error.equalsIgnoreCase(errormsg)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Username",username);
                intent.putExtra("Password",password);
               startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
```

And In my MainActivity2 class i created an object for MainActivity but it returns null values
.

Comment: Have you tried passing the information through an intent using the putExtra() method?

Comment: As @Aaron said you can pass it through intent. 2) You can use Pref value or 3) Use static variable.

Comment: @sathish This is not a proper way. You just change your whole question.

Answer (score 1):

You should store it on a static global class, say

```
public static class Credentials{
  public static String USERNAME = "myUsername";
  public static String PASSWORD = "myPassword";
}
```

Then you can access it anywhere on your project using:

```
Credentials.USERNAME = "setyourusername";
Credntials.PASSWORD = "setYourPassword;
```

But I wouldn't recommend this kind of implementation because it is really not secure, but as for an answer for your question, this probably is the approach you'll need.

Edit: 
If the information should only be shared between that two activities, then @Faysal Ahmed 's answer is the way to go.

After this line on your first activity:

```
username = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername)).getText().toString();
 password =((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword)).getText().toString();
```

you can assign it directly to the static credentials class:

```
Credentials.USERNAME = username;
Credntials.PASSWORD = password;
```

then you can access it on your second activity the same way by calling `Credentials.USERNAME` and `Credentials.PASSWORD`

Comment: but i want to retrieve username and from my edit text fields

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value from MainActivity then need to pass both values using putExtra.

```
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
     i.putExtra("username",username);
     i.putExtra("password",password);
     startActivity(i);
```

And from `Main2Activity` class you can get the value like this. Use this lines under `onCreate` method.

```
String user = getIntent.getStringExtra("username");
String pass =  getIntent.getStringExtra("password");
```

No need to use `MainActivity m = new MainActivity();` this line.

**UPDATE:**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String user;
    String pass;

    String JSON_URL = "http://182.18.163.39/m/list.php?username=admin&key=admin";
    ListView listView;
    java.util.List<List> tktList;

    String link;
    Button logoutbt;
    Button ubt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
       // Get value from intent that passed from previous Activity
        user = getIntent.getStringExtra("username");
        pass =  getIntent.getStringExtra("password");
       // Now you can use this two variable in any place. 

        logoutbt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.lbt);
        logoutbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences SM = getSharedPreferences("userrecord", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = SM.edit();
                edit.putBoolean("username", false);
                edit.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        //initializing listview and hero list
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        tktList = new ArrayList<>();

        //this method will fetch and parse the data
        loadHeroList();
    }

    private void loadHeroList() {
        //getting the progressbar
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        //making the progressbar visible
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //creating a string request to send request to the url
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //hiding the progressbar after completion
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        try {

                            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = jsonobject.getString("Sno");
                                String Tktid = jsonobject.getString("TKTID");
                                link = jsonobject.getString("Link");

                                List list = new List(jsonobject.getString("Sno"), jsonobject.getString("TKTID"),jsonobject.getString("Link"));
                                tktList.add(list);

                                Log.i("website content", name);
                                Log.i("website content", Tktid);
                                Log.i("website content", link);

                            }

                            //creating custom adapter object
                            ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(tktList, getApplicationContext());


                            //adding the adapter to listview
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        //creating a request queue
        com.android.volley.RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //adding the string request to request queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: @sathish I just updated my answer with MainActivity2 full class. Please check and try.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

Comment: got it i am getting the intent values outside the on create method now i created inside onCreate()

Comment: If your problem is fixed. Please mark this answer as accepted. Thanks and Happy to help you :-).

Comment: In my second activity i created a bundle for storing username and password from first activity and i am getting another variable (link) value from Adapter class but in that bundle only username and password are stored how to store the other value also

Comment: What you are trying to do. You want to pass username, password and selected link to Main3Activity? Are you using RecyclerView or ListView?  If you use this get click event from Activity page and then pass all data from Activity to Main3Activity.

Comment: I just updated please check it once i will get a clarity

Comment: This is not a proper way to update the question. You have a store the previous question details and just update the new details. Please update the question with previous details.

Comment: what my requirement is to carry the username and password which are enterd in edit text fields in Mainactivity to My MainAtivity2 and MainActivity3 also and here in MainActivity2 i am using a listview from That list Adapter i am sending a value called link.

Comment: Please try this first to get the click event on Activity: https://www.milesburton.com/Android_-_Building_a_ListView_with_an_OnClick_Position

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

1) First, create a POJO class like this:

```
public class Info {
    static Info info;
    private String userName;
    private String password;

        public static Info getInstance() {
        if (info == null) {
            info = new Info();
        }
        return info;

    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName= userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password= password;
    }
}
```

2) and then set your username and password like this:

```
Info.getInstance.setUserName("username");
Info.getInstance.setPassword("password");
```

3) and then get it like this in your other activities:

```
Info.getInstance.getUserName();
Info.getInstance.getPassword();
```

You can also pass your values to a intent and get those values in other activity.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Intent you can pass the credentials through like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityYouArePassingInformationTo.class); 

i.putExtra("username", userNameValue); 
i.putExtra("password", passwordValue);
```

Then in the activity that you want to receive the information you can get it through this way:

```
String userNameVal = intent.getStringExtra("username");
String passwordVal = intent.getStringExtra("password");
```

Now the variables in the MainActivity will have the username and password stored in a variable. Hope this helps :)

Comment: In my second activity i created a bundle for storing username and password from first activity and i am getting another variable (link) value from Adapter class but in that bundle only username and password are stored how to store the other value also

Answer (score 0):

If `username` and `password` are only used in second activity only then you can pass these values in `Intent`.

In `MainActivity`

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
i.putExtra("user_name", userName);
i.putExtra("password", password);
startActivity(i);
```

in `Main2Activity` `onCreate()` after `setContentView()` you can read data like this

```
Intent i = getIntent();
user = i.getStringExtra("user_name");
pass = i.getStringExtra("password");
```

Other ways are to save `username` and `password` in `SharedPreferences` in `MainActivity` and read `Main2Activity`. This might be useful when you want to auto fill previous `username` and `password` on next app launch.

Comment: Thanks for your hep

Comment: In my second activity i created a bundle for storing username and password from first activity and i am getting another variable (link) value from Adapter class
but in that bundle only username and password are stored how to store the other value also

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem.

1. You can use below code in MainActivity class.

> Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
>       i.putExtra("UserName",username);
>       i.putExtra("Password",password);
>       startActivity(i);

And in Main2Activity, you will get by using below code,

> ```
> Intent i = getIntent();
> String userName = i.getString("UserName");
> String password = i.getString("Password");
> ```

2. Use below snippet code in MainActivity after you will get userName and 
      passsword.

   ```
    SharedPreferences 
    pref=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("UserName", username);
    editor.putString("Password", password);
    editor.commit();
   ```

   And after this, you will get these values in Main2Activity by below code.

   ```
    SharedPreferences 
    pref=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    String userName = pref.getString("UserName", null);
    String password = pref.getString("Password", null);
   ```
3. You can use static UserName and Password and get static value in other 
   Activity. like,

   In MainActivity

> public static String userName, password;

and set value after getting userName and password

```
userName = "abc"
password = "***"
```

Now In Main2Activity you will get these values directly by class name

```
String userName = MainActivity.userName;
String password = MainActivity.password;
```

4. You can use setter and getter method. In MainActivity, When you will find the 
   values you have to set userName and password.
   Now, In Main2Activity you will get those values(UserName and Password) by 
   getter methods